# inbuilt function in opengl to get co-ordinates of final transformed point

Tags: opengl, graphics, transformation

Say,I have been given a point [x,y,z]. I apply some transformation matrix (composed of scaling,rotation and translation). Definitely I can write my own routine to get co-ordinates of final transformed point. Is there any in-built function in opengl to for the same..

This type of function might be well-optimized and what i will write may not be that much efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gluProject()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml):

```
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef( 90, 0, 0, 1 );
GLdouble modelview[16] = { 0 };
glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );

GLdouble identity[16] = { 
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
};
GLint view[4] = { -1, -1, 2, 2 };

// rotate (1,0,0) by 90 degrees around the Z axis:
double x, y, z;
gluProject( 1, 0, 0, modelview, identity, view, &x, &y, &z );
z = ( z * 2 ) - 1;

// x,y,z should equal (0,1,0)
```

Though you'd be better off using a proper matrix library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) since it's just a matrix-vector multiply.

Comment: you provided some quite "old" openGL code. Currently it is better to use some third party library (like you wrote). I am happy with GLM for instance